# PHP calculate days Between 2 different dates

Tags: php, mysql

Hello and thanks for the help. I have a table in mysql with 2 columns (date1),(date2).I want to find the days between these two days and calculate a price of 10 dollars for each day through php

Comment: This has been asked here **a lot**. Search this site and you'll find the code you need.

Comment: You can do this both with MySQL or with PHP, search around there's a lot of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime("@{$date1}");
$dt2 = new DateTime("@{$date2}");
$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
$price = 10 * $interval->d;
```

This assumes that you are saving your dates `$date1`and `$date2` as unix timestamps

Comment: i will try it, i need to get the dates from mysql

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?php
     $first_date = strtotime("2013-04-10");
     $last_date = strtotime("2013-04-01");
     $datediff = $first_date - $last_date;
     echo "Days : ". floor($datediff/(60*60*24))."<br>";
     echo "Price : $". (floor($datediff/(60*60*24)))*10;
?>
```

**Output**

```
Days : 9
Price : $90
```